# Excel 2010 Scroll into view fails in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a function that should scroll to a given cell in Excel 2010 using a macro.
So far, I've found plenty of ways to move the view where I want it, but none of them work within a macro (ie, typing them into the Immediate window works just fine, but inside the macro it does nothing at all). Only the Application.Goto function seems to do anything at all, but it ensures that the specified range is the top-left most cell displayed, not necessarily intuitive to my purposes.
Following is the relevant code that I'm trying to use. Preferably I want whatever the selection is (set beforehand by Cells(r,c).Select) should be within view within reason.

```
    'Note that the only one of these that seems to work is the next line
    'The rest only work when using the Immediate window. :/
    Application.Goto Reference:="R" & r & "C" & c, Scroll:=True
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Left, Selection.Top, Selection.Width, Selection.Height
    Selection.Show
```

One thing of note is that this macro is acting on other workbooks. I'm not sure why that might make a difference, but it's something that could possibly be interefering somehow?

The only workaround I can think of is to use the Application.Goto, but offset the value somehow. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this ended up being my oversight.
I had used Application.ScreenUpdating = False  to stop window flickering while opening the various workbooks. Once I commented that out they're working just fine now.

Comment: Did you put `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of the routine?

Comment: Yeah, I did have that at the very end, but if it was set to false then the window wouldn't move. IE, I would need to do Screenupdating=true just before the action and then set it back to false, which negated the point of doing that in the first place. :)